# How to push several function with args into an array

Tags: arrays, node.js, queue, node-modules

Hello everyone,

In a Node.js module (a custom queue) i am working on, 
I am using the [queue module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue), and I need to push into its array "jobs" several functions with an argument (an int for the estimated time)
When I start the queue, an error that says that the job is not a function. 
I think I understand why, it's because the function "process" is executed when I push it. But I need to execute this process later with arguments.

my code :

```
module.exports = Queue
var process = require("../test/processjob")
var q = require("queue");

function Queue(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Queue)) {
    return new Queue(options);
  }
  options = options || {}
  this.queue = q();
  /*
handling other options
*/
}

Queue.prototype.processJob = function() {

  for (var i = 0, len = this.tasks.length; i < len; i++) {

    this.queue.push(process.process(this.tasks[i].estimated_time));// <== push here
}
this.queue.start(); //<== exception here
}
```

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

To push a function into an array, that you'll want to execute at a later point in time, you could wrap that function with another function, i.e.:

```
this.queue.push(
  function(cb) {
    process.process(this.tasks[i].estimated_time)
    cb();
  }
);// <== push here
```

Or using ES6

```
this.queue.push((cb) => { 
   process.process(this.tasks[i].estimated_time);
   cb();
});
```

Comment: So, I tried your solution, and it seems to work partially, the exception is gone, but when a start the queue (with [queue.start()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue#qstartcb)) the jobs don't seems to process.

Comment: Ok let me have a look at the queue library that you mentioned to see if there's anything wrong in your implementation

Comment: I tried, but "this.tasks[i]" is undefined. I don't know how I could give this variable to process in my queue

Comment: I don't know what this.tasks[i] is supposed to be, but try outside of your for loop to do: var _this = this;  and inside use   _this.tasks[i]